# Batch SQL query to update a field from different table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

`Table t1 - Fields a, b
Table t2 - Fields a, c`

(a is common field between two tables)

I have added the field b in t2 and want to populate data for the same using references in t1

This can be done using following queries (e.g. a = 100, 101, ...)

`update t2 set b = (select b from t1 where a = 100 limit 1) where a = 100;`

`update t2 set b = (select b from t1 where a = 101 limit 1) where a = 101;`

Is there way this can be batched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
update t2 join
       t1
       on t2.a = t1.a
    set t2.b = t1.b;
```

You could also use a correlated subquery:

```
update t2
    set b = (select t1.b from t1 where t1.a = t2.a);
```

However, non-matching values would be set to `NULL`.